# Mark component as ClientOnly in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building a UI component library and have encountered some issues using it in Nuxt. I found out that some components that rely on the id, which is being generated on the component's creation, will lose their functionality because the id will be generated twice - once on the server, which will be rendered in the DOM, and then on the client side, where it will be used in the listeners bound in the onMounted hook.

I either have to rethink the whole logic or simply mark this component as `ClientOnly`. However, doing this manually in Nuxt for every occurrence feels wrong. Obviously, I have to manage this inside the component, but Vue doesn't have a built-in `ClientOnly` wrapper.

Is it possible to mark such components as `ClientOnly` in Vue?

Comment: There are third-party libs that do this. You didn't specify which Vue version it is